# Requested runtime (Python 3.7.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)

Tags: python, django, web, heroku

django (2.0)
    I am trying to upload my django app to heroku but i couldn't because it 
    says requested runtime(python 3.7.2) is not available.

```
Counting objects: 100% (1725/1725), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1721/1721), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1725/1725), 9.34 MiB | 21.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1725 (delta 93), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python 3.7.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mubashartech.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mubashartech.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mubashartech.git'
```

Comment: Note that Django 2.0 is end of life and no longer receives security updates. You should upgrade to the latest 2.2.X LTS.

Comment: Did you read the referenced devcenter support page? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support tell you that the support Python version is `python-3.7.3`. Update yor `runtime.txt` file.

Answer (score 3):

The [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version) show that the currently supported version of Python 3.7.X is 3.7.3.

Change the value in your `runtime.txt` file to `python-3.7.3` to use Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Requested runtime (Python 3.7.3) is not available for this stack (heroku-18). it shows this error again

Comment: Make sure you have exactly `python-3.7.3` and not something similar like `Python 3.7.3`. If that doesn’t help, I’m afraid I don’t have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

in the current herouku stack -20  , even 3.7.3 is not supported. check this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes)
Hence please use 3.7.10 in the runtime.txt file

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the supported python versions and align your runtime.txt file make sure it as follows **python-3.7.3** with no spacing, if your project is using an extremely lower version of python, you need to align to make sure you aren't using libraries that are not supported as per python-3.7X